# PHP Java Bridge: php_sqlite.dll library not found

Tags: php, sqlite, tomcat7, php-extension, php-java-bridge

I would like to ask about php java bridge. Curently I am working with php 5.2.9 on tomcat 7. I am running the php by using PHP Java Bridge. In this situation I would like to add some php extensions, such as sqlite, pdo, ldap, etc.

I have add the extension to folder ext ((D:\Tomcat\webapps\gasteparkplatze_03\WEB-INF\cgi\amd64-windows\ext) on my folder. And also I have add it to my php.ini (D:\Tomcat\webapps\gasteparkplatze_03\WEB-INF\cgi\amd64-windows)

But, I face a trouble. Everytime I start my tomcat, there is an error, that say the library is not found. I have checked the directory path many times and nothing is wrong with it.

Here is the content of my php.ini file:

```
;; -*- mode: Scheme; tab-width:4 -*-
;; A simple php.ini
;; DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!
;; Add your configuration files to the D:\Tomcat\webapps\JavaBridgeTemplate621\WEB-INF\cgi\amd64-windows\conf.d instead.
;; PHP extensions go to D:\Tomcat\webapps\JavaBridgeTemplate621\WEB-INF\cgi\amd64-windows\ext. Please see phpinfo() for ABI version details.
extension_dir="D:\Tomcat\webapps\gasteparkplatze_03\WEB-INF\cgi\amd64-windows\ext"
include_path="D:\Tomcat\webapps\gasteparkplatze_03\WEB-INF\pear;."

extension=php_sqlite.dll
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I’d say, try using `php -l` and `php -m` [on command line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) first to check whether PHP itself has any problems with your configuration. (Make sure it uses the same config file when running on console first.)

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. I have solved the problem by changing the "extension=php_sqlite.dll" into "extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved 'by changing the "extension=php_sqlite.dll" into "extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll"' in php.ini.

P.S. Try not to leave the questions unanswered.